# Restoring the files of a user and imposing per-session time limits for a user

Tags: windows-xp, windows-vista

Is there a way of restoring any changes the user makes to their documents (and restrict access to the C: drive) upon logoff/logon and impose a time limit for the users session and log them off after the set time limit?

I'm looking for a easy way of doing this where i can change the settings if i ever needed to without alot of effort.

The computers in question are running Windows XP/Vista.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Windows SteadyState to do this. It can impose time limits, restrict access to folders/files and stop the execution of applications to name a few features.

It's reasonably user friendly, you can basically select a user then configure limits for that user.

More information about features [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_SteadyState#Features) as the Microsoft page about it now 404's as it was discontinued in late 2010.

**Update:** Download link is [here](http://download.cnet.com/Windows-SteadyState/3000-18512_4-11127965.html). Click `Direct download link` (its below the large green download button) if you'd rather not install CNet's download application.